# Write on every other/second/etc. lines

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As you can see in the added picture to the thread:

### **Picture 1:**

I have attempted to say I am going to write on one line and then drop the next line; then write again on the third line and so on. Please let me know which option sounds incorrect and why?

- > 1.a. I am writing **every other line.** (I don't know if I have to use the preposition "on" here or not.)
- > 1.b. I am writing **every second line.** (I don't know if I have to use the preposition "on" here or not.)
- > 1.c. I am writing **on alternate lines.**

**Note:** to me all the three choices above work naturally and mean the same thing.

### **Picture 2:**

Now, let's say you are going to write on the first line, then then drop the **next two lines**; then write again and so on. I wonder which option doesn't work and why:

- > 2.a. I am writing **every three lines.** (I don't know if I have to use the preposition "on" here or not.)
- > 2.b. I am writing **every third line.** (I don't know if I have to use the preposition "on" here or not.)

**Note:** to me all the two choices above work naturally and mean the same thing.

Please have a look on my picture and let me know if I have been right or wrong in my options.

Also please kindly correct my mistakes if I have been incorrect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **line** can refer either to a line of script or a blank line.

If you are writing on a page with blank lines, you can write **on** every second line (by missing a line) or **on** every third line (by missing two lines). And so on.

Alternatively, as you suggest, you can refer to **every other line** or **every alternate line**. They mean the same thing.

**To write every second line** implies that you have a script, possibly a poem, and that you choose to write the words from one line and miss the words on the next. It might also be understood by some people to mean writing **on** every second line. The context would make it clear.

For example, you might choose to write down every second line of a poem because the final words of the first and third (second and fourth) lines rhymed.

The same applies if you choose to write every third line.

To say that **I am writing every three lines** is grammatically correct but requires a context to be meaningful.

Comment: So, If I'm not mistaken, you mean that (as I mentioned too,) 1.a. , 1.b. and 1.c. all mean exactly the same. The same goes with 2.a. and 2.b. which are the same too. Am I right @Ronald Sole?

Comment: Yes, 1a,1b & 1c mean the same thing. But 2a & 2b don't. Your illustration shows you writing **on** every third line, not **writing every third line**. **To write every third line** is not clear but suggests that you are choosing to copy what is on every third line of a script and omitting the two preceding lines.

Comment: Thank you @Tonal Sole, but I was wondering as my last question, what about "**to write on every three lines**"? Is it the same as "**to write on every third line**"?

Comment: @A-friend No it's not. To write on every three lines means that you miss lines that do no come in threes, but it's not clear. It's possible for instance that in a book there are sections with two lines, with three lines, with four lines and so on. You might be writing only on the areas with three lines. But, as I say, the meaning is not clear to the reader without further context.

Comment: Hence, @Ronald Sole the only clear way to say that would be **to write on every third / fourth/ fifth line** which is clear to all. Right?

Comment: @A-friend It's the clearest and simplest. You could say: **leave one (or two or three) blank lines after each line you write on** but that's just a long-winded way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, you do need to include "on."

*To write a line* ordinarily means to compose a piece of dialogue, a piece of a poem, or in some contexts, a sentence.  If you "write every other line," it means that the lines must already exist - so you can't be composing them.  In this case, you must be rewriting them, or transcribing them.

For example, I'll "write every other line" of *This Is Just to Say* by William Carlos Williams:

> I have eaten
>
> that were in
>
> and which
>
> saving
>
> Forgive me
>
> so sweet

(Here's the whole thing, if you don't know it: https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56159/this-is-just-to-say)

But, aside from this point, all your sentences are correct. The sentences with "every second line" and "every third line" are slightly ambiguous. They could either mean what you've shown in the picture, or they could mean *begin writing on the second line, then write on the fourth line, then the sixth, etc.* (or, the third, sixth, ninth, etc).

Comment: So @Juhasz do you mean "to write **on** every other line" or "to write **on** second line" or "to write **on** every three lines" or "to write **on** every third line"?